# Can the lack of obstruction to deforming a checkerboard tessellation be seen as part of a larger picture?

Tags: homology-cohomology, tessellations

All quadrilaterals, even the nonconvex ones, tessellate the plane.  One way to see this is to start from a checkerboard tessellation made by repeatedly flipping squares across their edges, and then note that you can deform the vertices of each square as much as you like and the tessellation is preserved.

As everyone knows, obstructions to geometric constructions always live in some cohomology group or other for completely mysterious reasons.  Is there some nice invariant that attaches to a -- I don't know the appropriate object here, maybe some sort of periodic lattice -- that we could have calculated to determine that we could deform the squares of the checkerboard into arbitrary quadrilaterals?

Obviously this could be a pretty open-ended question, but on the other hand I feel like there might be a known answer here, and if so the question is fairly clear-cut.  (Feel free to insert additional hypotheses if necessary.)

Comment: I am actually working on classifying obstructions of 'rigid' homological character to tiling as a means of extending the results of an older result of mine.  I will be very interested (and maybe a little anxious - nobody likes being beaten!) in answers to this question.  In the meantime, a nice read is 'Algebra and Tiling: Homomorphisms in the service of geometry'.  In the context of tiling, I do not think 'homology' is precisely the right word.  I am trying to find the right word, but my context is high dimensional translation tilings.

Comment: @guest: Any updates?

Comment: Well, admittedly my interests have shifted away from this field so I cannot say I have updates.  The reference I gave does give homological obstructions to tiling, but not obstructions to deformations.  The problem is, what is a deformation really?  How do I tell a deformation of a square tiling from, say, a tiling by disconnected tiles?